# How to simplify long list of similar if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement

I work as an automation engineer for my company. Recently, I wrote a piece of code that my manager absolutely would not accept.

I was asked to write some scripts for test cases involving different pieces of the GUI. The part of the code my manager would not accept was an `if/else` statement meant to check the current language of the prompt in the GUI.

I've been instructed to use Sikuli, and as such, it is very important that I know what language the application is currently set to so my scripts can click the correct buttons (which change depending on the language).

My thoughts were that the code iterates through the `if/else` statement and then points to the correct button. Example: The `if/else` statement determines that the "ok" button is currently the Suomi translation, so it will than click the correct button.

Here is an example of my code:

```
switch (button) {
case "ok":
    if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/catalan_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/catalan_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/suomi_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/suomi_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/italian_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/italian_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/portuguese_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/portuguese_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/english_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/english_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/dutch_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/dutch_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/spanish_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/spanish_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/french_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/french_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/latina_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/latina_ok.png");
                        } else if (s.exists("imagerepo/language/chinese_ok.png") != null) {
                            s.click("imagerepo/language/chinese_ok.png");
                        }
break;
...etc..
```

My only gripe with the above code is that it is pretty ugly. Functionally it does exactly what I'd like it to, 100% of the time.

EDIT: I figure that having a switch that adapts to the potentially changing button would be better than having 10 switches for the same button. Arguably, against what I just said, if I'm writing the scripts, I will always know what language the system is going to be in.

If this is an example of poor code, what could I do instead to determine which "form" of the button I need to press?

It would be worth noting now that the answer I'm looking for does not actually pertain to testing at all, but rather, how do I optimally perform the function of that `if/else` block above?

Comment: Consider using a switch statement!

Comment: @TangledUpInBlue It's actually in a switch for "ok" already (edited that part out, if that's important I'll throw it back in). So when I call the switch with the "ok" parameter, it would click the correct "ok" button.

Comment: My general rule of thumb is if the if statements take more than 3 lines, then there is probably a better way to do it, or maybe I should be using a `private boolean` method to make it readable. I'd make it as an `isOkPng()`method. Vlad's answers is probably the best for this situation.

Comment: Consider using a map.

Comment: It looks like you're doing your own internationalization. Perhaps using some of the standard Java functionality for internationalization would help not just with this part of the code but with others too. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like:

```
String[] languages = {
  "catalan_ok.png",
  "suomi_ok.png",
  //...
}

for (String base : languages) {
  String file = String.format("imagerepo/language/%s", base);
  if (s.exists(file) != null) {
    s.click(file);
    break;
  }
}
```

perhaps? Not tested.

Comment: I was about to suggest the very same. Ugly pieces of code may become beautifull data structures.

Comment: I think that's the best option.

Comment: This works absolutely beautifully. This type of data structure allows me to easily iterate not just through the "ok" button forms, but the "cancel" forms as well. It also allows me to avoid many lines of code that would otherwise be `switch` or `if/else` blocks. Thanks Vlad, real eye opening.

Comment: Lists and Map are very fundamental concepts. If "this type of data structre" feels unnatural to you, you should read up on them. Also you should read up on the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that this is for internationalization so you could use a properties file for each language and then get the image path like this

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "messages", userLocale );
s.click(bundle.getString("image"));
```